# Custom Shell Seg Faulting

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to make a custom shell for a class assignment. The TLDR is... I don't really know what's wrong with it. From the debugging, it looks like there's an error in the loop() function, but I don't know why, or where the error exists.

What's happening is the application executes the command correctly. However, on the next loop for the next command input, it segfaults. I've tried to make sure all the variables are freed so I'm not writing attempting to write into memory that I can't. That's the major issue. The second (much more minor) issue is that I can't get piping to work. I'm also not sure why. I thought I re-wrote stdin/stdout correctly. (Yes, I know strtok id deprecated. I do plan on moving to "strtok_r")

Does anyone have guidance or suggestions on what I'm not doing correctly?

Cheers,
M

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a\v" // \a is Alert. \v is vertical tab.
#define FG_EXEC 0
#define BG_EXEC 1
#define MAXARG 20
#define CMD_MAX 100 //Some arbitrary value...

/* Set up Command Segements */
struct cmd_seg {
    char *args[MAXARG];
    struct cmd_seg *next; // Linked List. Next node
};

struct cmd {
    struct cmd_seg *root;
    int mode; //BG, FG
};

/* Helper Functions - Core Functionality */
void cd(char *path){
    int code = chdir(path); //May only return -1 (error) or 0 (success)
    if(code == -1){
        printf("\nFailed to change your path to \"%s\"\n", path);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nChanged path to: %s\n", path);
    }
}

/* Helper Functions - Job Control */
void bg(pid_t pid){
    int status;
    if(kill(pid, SIGCONT) < 0){ printf("\nBG: JNF"); }
    else{ waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED); }
}

void fg(pid_t pid){
    setpgid(pid, pid);
    int status;
    if (tcsetpgrp(1, getpgid(pid)) != 0){
        printf("\nFG: JNF");    
    }
    else{
        kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    }
}

/* Helper Functions - PID, Child, Forks, etc */
void kill_child(pid_t pid){ // What an unforunate name... Dark humour.
    kill(pid, SIGTERM); //Safe Termination. SIGKILL may ne required?
}

/*
void destroyList(struct cmd** cmd1){
    struct cmd* cmd_cur = cmd1;
    struct cmd_seg* cs_cur;
    struct cmd_seg* next;
    cs_cur = cur->root;
    while(cs_cur != NULL){
        next = cs_cur->next;
        free(cs_cur);
        cs_cur = next;
    }
    free(cs_cur);
    free(cmd1);
}
*/

/* Helper Functions - Check for Built-in Command */
int builtins(struct cmd_seg *segment){
    /* Check for Internal Commands - CD, Exit, etc */
    if(strcmp(segment->args[0], "cd") == 0){
        cd(segment->args[1]);
        char path[PATH_MAX];
        getcwd(path, sizeof(path));
        printf("%s%%", path);
        fflush(stdout);
        return 1;
    }
    else if(strcmp(segment->args[0], "exit") == 0){
        printf("\nExiting Core Application.\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    /*
    else if(strcmp(segment->args[0], "kill") == 0){
        pid_t pid;
        pid = atoi(segment->args[1]);
        if(pid!=0){ // if 0, implies it's not an integer, failed extraction;
            kill_child(pid);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    */
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

int exec_cmd_seg(struct cmd_seg *segment, int in_fd, int out_fd, int mode, int pGrpID){
    int status = 1;
    int IsBuiltin = builtins(segment);

    if(IsBuiltin == 0){ return -1; }
    else if(IsBuiltin == 1){ return 1; }
        /* 
        * Not a Builtin Command, Application has not Exited
        * Therefore fork
        */
        pid_t child_pid;
        child_pid = fork();
        if(child_pid < 0){
            printf("\nForking failed - Exiting Gracefully");
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(child_pid == 0){
            /* Forked */
            int damnPIDs = getpid();
            if(mode == FG_EXEC){ printf("\nFG Execution @ PID %d", damnPIDs); }
            else{ printf("\nBG Execution @ PID %d", damnPIDs); }

            signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
            signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
            signal(SIGCONT, SIG_DFL);

            /* Re-write In-Outs */
            dup2(in_fd, 0);
            dup2(out_fd, 1);

            if(in_fd != 0){
                close(in_fd);
            }
            else if(out_fd != 1){
                close(out_fd);
            }

            /* Check args[1] */
            int result = execvp(segment->args[0], segment->args);
            if(result < 0){
                printf("\nError Executing Command: %s", segment->args[0]);
                //exit(0);
            }
        }
        else{
            signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
            signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
            signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
            if (mode == BG_EXEC) 
                signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
            else 
                waitpid(child_pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
            if(in_fd != 0){
                close(in_fd);
            }
            if(out_fd != 1){
                close(out_fd);
            }
        return 1;
        }
    return 1;
}

int exec_cmd(struct cmd *command){
    int status = 1;
    struct cmd_seg* cur;
    struct cmd_seg* pfree;
    int fd = 0;
    //int count = 0;
    //printf("\nEXEC_CMD: Entering For1");
    //fflush(stdout);
    for(cur = command->root; cur != NULL; cur = cur -> next){
        //printf("\nExec_CMD - Command %d: %s", count, command->root->args);
        //fflush(stdout);
        if(cur -> next){
            //printf("\nExec_CMD - Command %d: %s", count, cur->args);
            //fflush(stdout);
            int fd2[2];
            pipe(fd2);
            status = exec_cmd_seg(cur, fd, fd2[1], command->mode, 0);
            fd = fd2[0];
        }
        else{
            status = exec_cmd_seg(cur, fd, 1, command->mode, 0);
        }

        cur = command -> root;
        pfree = cur;
        while(cur != NULL){
            cur = cur -> next;
            
            /* Clear pfree before setting it */
            free(pfree);
            pfree = cur;
        }
    }
    cur = NULL;
    pfree = NULL;
    free(command);
    command = NULL;
    return status;
}

/* Fix to use strtok_r */
struct cmd* parser(char *line){
    struct cmd* command = (struct cmd*)malloc(sizeof(struct cmd));
    command->root = (struct cmd_seg*)malloc(sizeof(struct cmd_seg));
    struct cmd_seg* cur;
    struct cmd_seg* pnew;
    cur = command->root; 
    /* Check if it is background command */
    char* pStart = line; //pointer
    int count = 0;
    while ((*pStart != '\n') && (*pStart != '\0')) {
        if (*pStart == '&') {
            count = 1;
            *pStart = '\0';
            break;
        }
        pStart++;
    }
    command->mode = count;
    /* Parse line as command Link list */
    char *res = line;
    char *temp;
    int i = 0;
    temp = strsep(&res, "|");
    for (i = 0; i < MAXARG - 1 && (cur->args[i] = strtok(temp, TOK_DELIM)) != NULL; i++)
        temp  = NULL;
    cur->args[i] = NULL;
    while ((temp = strsep(&res, "|")) != NULL) {
        pnew = (struct cmd_seg*) malloc(sizeof(struct cmd_seg));
        cur->next = pnew;
        cur = pnew;
        for (i = 0; i < MAXARG - 1 && (cur->args[i] = strtok(temp, TOK_DELIM)) != NULL; i++)
            temp = NULL;
        cur->args[i] = NULL;
    }
    cur->next = NULL;
    //free(cur);
    //free(pnew);
    //free(pStart);
    return command;
}

char* readLine(){
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*CMD_MAX);
    char ch;
    int pos = 0;
    if(buffer){
            //printf("Inside Buffer If");
            //fflush(stdout);
            while(1){
                ch = getchar();
                //printf("Inside While\n");
                //fflush(stdout);
                /* Buffer Allocated */
                if(ch == EOF || ch == '\n'){
                    printf("Command: %s\n", buffer);
                    return buffer;
                }
                else{
                    buffer[pos] = ch;
                }
                pos++;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Allocation Failed\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        exit(0);
    }
}

void loop(){
    
    /* Loop Command Input */
    int status = 1;
    //int l_count = 0;
    while(status >= 0){
        char *line;
        struct cmd *cmd;
        //printf("Inside Loop - 1\n");
        //fflush(stdout);

        /* Print Shell Prompt */
        char path[PATH_MAX];
        getcwd(path, sizeof(path));
        printf("%s%%", path);
        fflush(stdout);

        line = readLine();
        if(strlen(line) == 0){
            printf("Failed to read line.");
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            cmd = parser(line);
            if(cmd!=NULL){
                //printf("\nCMD not null - executing");
                //fflush(stdout);
                status = exec_cmd(cmd);
            }
            else{
                printf("\nFailed to parse command correctly");
                fflush(stdout);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        free(line);
        //free(cmd);
        //free(path); Not a heap device -- GCC Output
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    loop();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `readLine` never adds a null terminator to the end of the string.

Comment: `ch` should be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `fgets()` instead of reading character by character?

Comment: What does your question have to do with `gdb`?

Comment: I have switched to fgets(), it hasn't made any impact. fgets() will also add a termination string, it hasn't assisted.

ch and pos are useless now, so I'll disregard those suggestions. It's still resulting in a  segfault immediately after executing a command (exception being "exit" which is built in). GDB still points to a segfault in loop().

Comment: Why do you use `while()` loops when `for()` loops are so much easier (and three lines shorter) and less error-prone?

Comment: Are you trying to point me in the right direction by using for() instead of while()? The while() loop in the loop() function is basic at best. It's simply always try, no need for a for() loop there. I can re-write the while loops in other places, but I don't think it'll make a difference.

Comment: Where did you hear that `strtok()` is deprecated?

Comment: There's too much code to read here to try to find your problem. I suggest using `valgrind` to help find it.

Comment: strtok() being "deprecated" was a poor choice of words. It's simply unsafe for use. I have actually solved the segfault issue. In the debug output of GCC (-Wall) one of my functions was returning an "control reached end of function without return" so I moved the final return statement. I inserted another return statement two lines below, which solves the segfault issue and the GCC Warnings.

Comment: I just took a quick look, and all the functions that have return types seem to end with appropriate `return` statemetns. Which function was it? You should post the fix as an Answer below, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The segfault occurs in the *for* statement. The body of the for-loop has executed one time, then the *loop-expression* `cur = cur->next` is executed, but `cur` is NULL.

It's NULL because of some code in the body of the for-loop which frees all the `cmd_seg`s in the linked list (I suspect that code is supposed to be after the for-loop rather than inside it).

```
int exec_cmd(struct cmd *command){
    int status = 1;
    struct cmd_seg* cur;
    struct cmd_seg* pfree;

    for(cur = command->root; cur != NULL; cur = cur -> next){
        if(cur -> next){
            ...
        }

        cur = command -> root;
        pfree = cur;
        while(cur != NULL){
            cur = cur -> next;
            free(pfree);
            pfree = cur;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The *cond-expression* `cur != NULL` doesn't catch this because it is executed after the *init-expression* and then **after** each *loop-expression*.

After I fixed this by moving the `cmd_seg`-freeing code to be after the for-loop, I looked at pipeline commands, but they all succeeded for me.